# Multiple DataSources, Multiple Transaction Managers. Which one is used?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a SI configuration that is made up of multiple data sources. 
Say: DataSource A - Connects to Oracle
     DataSource B - Connects to DB2
     DataSource C - Connects to MySQL

One of the SI sub-flows writes to two of these data sources and I would like to do that in a 1-PC transaction.

So I define a ChainedTransactionManager with DataSource A and DataSource B. Let's call this chainedTransactionMgr

I also have two jdbc templates templateA(with A as it's datasource) and templateB (with B as it's datasource)

Let's say that I have a flow where I send a message to a publish-subscribe channel with two recipients that are service-activators that just use templateA and templateB to write the msg to their respective data source. Will the chained transaction manager be utilized in this flow?

Answer (score 1):

Everything what you say is good and correct.

Only the problem that you have to do all the job in a single thread, because that is only the way how you can involve several resources to one transaction. Actually this is a case when you use `publish-subscribe-channel` with default configuration, where in the same thread first subscriber will call its `templateA`; and only after that the second service will call its `templateB`.

So, the `ChainedTransactionManager` should be configured with that order, too.

And from here it even doesn't matter if you use XA transaction manager. The main point is **single thread**.

Comment: Do I need to inject the chained transaction manager any where? I have a sub-flow that is a couple of service-activator calls that write to the DB. They run on the same thread and the order in which they invoke the DB is the same order in which the ChainedTransactionManager has the resources but the transaction manager is not used. Do I need to explicitly start a transaction?

Comment: Of course, you have to start TX. Please, read Reference Manual on the matter for possible places to start TX: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html